# Make a synchronous Retrofit call from inside an OkHttp Interceptor

Tags: android, interceptor, retrofit, okhttp

I am trying to automatically refresh an `auth token` if it is expired.  I am using the new `Interceptor` class that was introduced in `OkHttp 2.2`.  In the `intercept` method I am trying the original request with `chain.proceed(request)`, checking the response code, and if the token is expired I am making a call to a separate Retrofit service, synchronously, to obtain a new token.

The strange thing is, no code past the synchronous call seems to run.  If I try debugging with a breakpoint on the synchronous call's line, then do a step-over, I am stopped in Dispatcher.java at :

```
if (!executedCalls.remove(call)) throw new AssertionError("Call wasn't in-flight!");
```

Any idea as to what I might be doing wrong here?  I could probably just craft a new request by hand, but I am just kind of curious why a `Retrofit call` doesn't seem to work here.

**My Interceptor**:

```
public class ReAuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        // try the request
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);

        // if we receive a "401 - Not Authorized" then refresh the auth token and try again
        if (response.code() == 401) {
            // get a new auth token and store it
            UserToken userToken = MobileClient.getOkraService().login(AuthUtil.getUserToken(MSWorksApplication.getContext()));
            AuthUtil.authenticate(MSWorksApplication.getContext(), userToken);

            Log.d("TEST", "TEST TEST TEST");

            // use the original request with the new auth token
            Request newRequest = request.newBuilder().header("Authorization", AuthUtil.getAuthToken(MSWorksApplication.getContext())).build();

            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
        else {
            // the auth token is still good
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you include the code of your Interceptor?

Comment: Your Authorization Header seems to me it is duplicated in the Headers of the request. This might happen because when you call .newBuilder() existing headers are copied to the new instance of the builder. How about you try to build request from scratch? Copy everything but headers from the previous session.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem - if you're getting an HTTP response code that would cause Retrofit to call failure() instead of success() an exception will be thrown.

If you wrap

```
UserToken userToken = MobileClient.getOkraService().login(AuthUtil.getUserToken(MSWorksApplication.getContext()));
```

in a try/catch(RetrofitError e) you'll be able to execute code after a failure, however I've found this to be quite cumbersome and am still in the process of finding a nicer solution.