# Handle before request calls Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm working with my own app with APIs, i want to handle something like `before request calls`. Which mean before an API be call, i can check and do something, after that, API will be continue calling.

For example, I have 2 APIs named `settings` and `login`.

When user want to login, user has to call api `login`. But i want to check if api `settings` didn't be call before, it will call `settings` first, when it done, call `login`.

If i use normally checking like a draft below, i have to check and write duplicate code too much.

```
if (settingDoesntCalled()){
  callSetting(){
     onResponse(){
       callLogin();
     }
  }
}else{
   callLogin();
}
```

And I have alot of APIs, which always want to check `settings` API first.

Any idea will helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a concept of [Interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) in Retrofit. It executes on the same thread as original network call, so you can pin and check whether this is Login network call and execute settings network call before.

Comment: U mean i can create a request inside `public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException` ?

Comment: Exactly. Another example is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226765/make-a-synchronous-retrofit-call-from-inside-an-okhttp-interceptor).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try it and feedback later.